# iphone sdk: how to end movie on tap of the screen?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have MPMoviePlayerController, with which I play a movie. I have my movieControlMode MPMovieControlModeHidden. I want this behaviour: while the movie plays, if tap on the screen is received, stop it, release the movie player. How can this be done?

```
mMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mMovieURL];
[mMoviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
mMoviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
[mMoviePlayer play];
```

How can I add target/event handler?

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be to place an invisible UIButton, covering the entire screen, which, on touchUpInside, calls a function to stop, release and remove the moviePlayer.